# Focus ring is not shown with programmatically created controls

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am working on some general dialogs for our content management system. Everything is written programmatically in Cocoa/Objective-C without using xib files.

Unfortunately the focus ring is never displayed, even though I can use TAB to move between the controls, and even though all controls are (or are inherited from) standard controls like NSButton, NSTextField and NSTextView.

On the other side, if I use xib files or storyboard files to make similar dialogs, the focus ring is shown without problems.

I expected that you only would need to draw the focus ring yourself if you are creating a custom view, which is directly inherited from NSView itself, regardless if you are using xib files or not.

Can anyone please help with this? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: have you tried setting NSFocusRingType properties?             NSFocusRingTypeDefault = 0,
      NSFocusRingTypeNone = 1,
      NSFocusRingTypeExterior = 2

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Unfortunately this does not change the appearance, the focus ring is still not shown.